# Global variable updated inside a function, however not being updated even with a function doing it

Tags: javascript

I'm currently in the making of a job menu for a game. I have declared a global variable at the top of the code, and I'd like to update it from within a function. I want it to be updated globally once it has been changed in the function, something that  I believe it does without doing anything extra (as far as I have read, used to c++ where it's completely different).

However, I got a second function named init() that is being run before everything else. Is there any way that I can retrieve the playerJob that is being updated in the window.addEventListener and do so I can use it within the init() function? As it is being run before the window.addEventListener?

I tried to just simply put the init() below the window.addEventListener, but that didn't do much.

Here's the full code commented (some of it is not relevant, added "NOT RELEVANT" to some of it:
https://pastebin.com/1i6AjeMX

```
var playerJob = ""; // global playerJob varaible that i'd like to update in the function below

$( function() {
// This is the second function
// Need it to access the window.addEventListener first to retrieve the player's job
// This because, as you can see in the init function, it needs to know the value of playerJob
// in order to show the right data-require.
    init();

// Gets the actionmenu div container        - NOT RELEVANT HERE
var actionContainer = $( "#actionmenu" );

// Listens for NUI messages from Lua 
// This needs to be accessed before init() as it has the playerJob data in it.
window.addEventListener( 'message', function( event ) {
    var item = event.data;


    // Show the menu 
    if ( item.showmenu ) {
        ResetMenu()
        actionContainer.show();
    }

    // Hide the menu 
    if ( item.hidemenu ) {
        actionContainer.hide(); 
    }


    if ( item.updateJob ) {
        // update the job variable 

        console.log("before set playerJob")
        playerJob = item.job; 
        console.log("playerJob set to: ")
        console.log(playerJob)

        // Obviously the console log returns the correct value of the playerJob, however
        // it doesn't seem to update the global variable shown in the start of the code
    }

    console.log("after the whole item updatejob")
    console.log(playerJob)
    // Here it doesn't show the value that was updated in the function above, however
    // it returns the value of the playerJob that I assigend globally, which is = "" - empty
    // My goal is to update the playerJob in the window.addEventListener and also update the global variable
    // at the same time

} );
} )

console.log("this is the job outside after update: ")
console.log(playerJob)
// this doens't work. Still empty, hasn't been updated from the 
window.addEventListener - returning the global = "" one

// Hides all div elements that contain a data-parent, in            -- NOT 
RELEVANT HERE
// other words, hide all buttons in submenus. 
function ResetMenu() {
$( "div" ).each( function( i, obj ) {
    var element = $( this );

    if ( element.attr( "data-parent" ) ) {
        element.hide();
    } else {
        element.show();
    }
} );
}

// Configures every button click to use its data-action, or data-sub                        
-- NOT RELEVANT HERE
// to open a submenu. 


function init() {
// Loops through every button that has the class of "menuoption"
$( ".menuoption" ).each( function( i, obj ) {

    // If the button has a data-action, then we set it up so when it is 
    // pressed, we send the data to the lua side. 
    if ( $( this ).attr( "data-action" ) ) {
        $( this ).click( function() { 
            var data = $( this ).data( "action" ); 

            sendData( "ButtonClick", data ); 
        } )
    }

    // If the button has a data-sub, then we set it up so when it is 
    // pressed, we show the submenu buttons, and hide all of the others.
    if ( $( this ).attr( "data-sub" ) ) {
        $( this ).click( function() {
            var menu = $( this ).data( "sub" );
            var element = $( "#" + menu ); 
            element.show();
            $( this ).parent().hide();  
        } )
    }

    // wk_actionmenu        THIS is where I'd love to access the playerJob     
updated in the window.addEventListener
    if ( ( $( this ).attr ( "data-require" ) == "police" && playerJob != 
"police") ) {
        $( this ).hide();
    }
} );

}

// Send data to lua for processing.             -- NOT RELEVANT HERE
function sendData( name, data ) {
$.post( "http://wk_actionmenu/" + name, JSON.stringify( data ), function( datab ) {
    if ( datab != "ok" ) {
        console.log( datab );
    }            
} );
}
```

Comment: Just call `init()` again inside of your listener?

Comment: Wish it'd be that easy. If you see "after the whole update" console.log, it returns undefined afterwards.

Comment: What's the data-type of `item.updateJob` during Truthy and Falsey conditions?

Comment: It is a message that is being sent from a game scripted in LUA. It does get updated as soon as the player presses a button, so the message is being set to true and then updates the playerJob. Perhaps not neccessary, but I'll be updating playerJob further more later in the game, so I guess it's alright to make it a true false, so whenever I set it to true it updates. Hope that answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

The part where you have

```
console.log("this is the job outside after update: ")
console.log(playerJob)
```

is not happening after the event listener fires. You have just put those log statements after you *register* the event listener:

```
window.addEventListener( 'message', function( event ) { ...
```

This part should work fine (notice the log method can take any number of args):

```
if ( item.updateJob ) {
    // update the job variable 

    console.log("before set playerJob")
    playerJob = item.job; 
    console.log("playerJob set to: ", playerJob)
}

console.log("after the whole item updatejob", playerJob);
```

after you *know* the 'message' event listener has fired, you should see those logs in the console (if `item.updateJob` is truthy), then you can type `playerJob` in the console and it should be updated